# В чем разница между "static final" VS "final"?

Tags: java, static, final

`static final` и `final`.

Оба значения константы и изменению не подлежат.

В чем же разница?

Comment: final - константа, static - переменная, которая принадлежит классу, а не объекту (единая для всех объектов). static и final - в принципе вещи из разных миров, разница такая же , как между самолетом и слоном

Comment: Поля с модификатором final static будут инициализироваться один раз при загрузке (инициализации) класса и хранится всё время (или то время пока востребован класс), а поля с модификатором final будут каждый раз создаваться в момент создания экземпляра класса (по крайней мере исходя из определения), для каждого экземпляра, и уничтожатся сборщиком мусора после того как экземпляр перестаёт использоваться. Но возможно сегодня оптимизатор более сложное поведение упрощает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`final` - значит неизменяемая, если быть точнее, то разрешается только одна операция присвоения

`static` - означает единая для всех экземпляров класса.

```
class Foo {
    static final int FOO1=1;
    final int foo2;
}
```

В данном примере:

- для всех экземпляров класса `Foo` переменная `FOO1` всегда будет равна `1`
- переменная `foo2` - может быть разной для разных экземпляров класса `Foo`

При этом оба безусловно неизменяемые.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с общего. static и final являются модификаторами.

На этом пожалуй всё.

**Static** - с англ.  "статичный", "постоянный" - делает переменную или метод "независимыми" от объекта. [Link](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/modifikator-static-v-java-metody/)

А суть модификатора **final** - сделать дальнейшее изменение объекта невозможным. [Link](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/modifikator-final/)

Т.е. Эти модификаторы находятся совсем в разных плоскостях взаимодействия на то, к чему они были пременены.

Это и является ответов на Ваш вопрос.

Если же вы хотите понять, что такое static и final и с чем это всё едят, то рекомендую ознакомиться ссылками представленные выше. Так как не возможно описать эти модификаторы один предложения не целяя за собой ряд тем. Уже всё хорошо описано в книгах по теме или же смело гуглить по каждому модификатору.

Comment: я знаю что такое static и final. прочитайте еще раз вопрос, и какую именно разницу я пытаюсь понять.

Comment: @Wlad, так разница в `static` - является ли константа глобальной, или принадлежит конкретному объекту.

Comment: я это понимаю. а вопрос, кстати, как раз и возник, из-за того, что наткнулся на эти статьи. именно ЭТИ! и в них не объяснялось разницы. я пометил ответ, который донес мысль до меня.

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко ([если подробно](https://linexp.ru/javabooks/Part_7_Thinking_in_Java_4th_edition.html#.D0.9A.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE_final)):

Ключевое слово static указывает, что константа существует в единственном числе.

Ключевое слово final указывает, что значение константы остается неизменным.

Константа с ключевыми словами static и final, существует в памяти в единственном экземпляре и ее значение не может быть изменено.